# Mockito: TooManyActualInvocations

Tags: java, mockito

I have a class with a method (executeLocal) that I want to test:

```
    public class SDExecuter {
    ...    
    public boolean executeLocal() {
                steps++;
                resetDisturbance();
                for (;;) {
                    try {
                        Event event = initialEventSequence.getFirst();
                        if (event.getActualEventTime() < timeManager.roundLocaTime(steps
                                * timeManager.getTps())) {
                            initialEventSequence.remove(event);
                            calculateIntervalBetweenEvents(event);
                            actualizedEventSequence.add(event);
                            continue;
                        }
                        informWithDisturbanceTorque();
                        break;
                    } catch (NoSuchElementException nsee) {
                        informWithDisturbanceTorque();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
    ...
    public void informWithDisturbanceTorque() {
            if (hasDisturbed) {
                disturbanceControl.setDistrubanceTorque(disturbanceTorqueVector);
            }
        }
...
    }
```

Specifically I want to test the number of calls of method informWithDisturbanceTorque() and so the number of calls to method setDistrubanceTorque:

```
 public class DisturbanceControl{
...
 public void setDistrubanceTorque(VectorColumn3d disturbanceTorqueVector){
        System.out.println("have a call with argument: " + disturbanceTorqueVector);
        this.disturbanceTorqueVector = disturbanceTorqueVector;
    }
...
}
```

This method print a message with received arguments to console when method is called.

I make a mockito spy for an object of the class:

```
spyDisturbanceControl = spy(new DisturbanceControl(null));
```

and make some invocations of the method that has been reflected with the console:

```
have a call with argument: {{-1.0}, {0.0}, {-1.0}}
have a call with argument: {{0.0}, {-1.0}, {0.0}}
```

The problem is: when I verify number of calls with the help of:

```
 @Test
public void executeLocalTest() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        sdExecuter.executeLocal();
        if (timeManager.getStepNumber() == eventTact[2]) {
            verify(spyDisturbanceControl, times(1)).setDistrubanceTorque(
                    new VectorColumn3d(-1.0d, 0.0d, -1.0d));
        }
        if (timeManager.getStepNumber() == eventTact[3]) {
            verify(spyDisturbanceControl, times(1)).setDistrubanceTorque(
                    new VectorColumn3d(0.0d, -1.0d, 0.0d));
        }
        timeManager.makeTimeStep();
    }
}
```

test ends up with an error:

```
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.579 sec <<< FAILURE!
executeLocalTest(test.SDExecuterTest)  Time elapsed: 0.5 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations: 
disturbanceControl.setDistrubanceTorque(
    {{0.0}, {-1.0}, {0.0}}
);
Wanted 1 time:
-> at test.SDExecuterTest.executeLocalTest(SDExecuterTest.java:92)
But was 2 times. Undesired invocation:
-> at test.SDExecuter.informWithDisturbanceTorque(SDExecuter.java:197)

    at test.SDExecuterTest.executeLocalTest(SDExecuterTest.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
```

Comment: But you called it twice.

Comment: You should probably use `times(2)` since you invoke it twice...

Comment: But with different arguments.. There are two different invocations. Isn't it?

Comment: Hmmyup, didn't see that... Can you paste the rest of Mockito's error message?

Comment: Just one question: do you use the method with one instance but check with another? Show more code...

Comment: Yes, it is so... And I add some more details about code and the test error.

Comment: I know this is very old, but for those digging through here, it may be that the #equals() method for VectorColumn3D is either not overriden or it doesn't correctly detect the differences.  In that case, the same verify will get triggered twice, even though the actual VectorColumn3D arguments were different

Comment: Did anyone solve this error ? I have similar error